# Circular signs with blue edges

Tags: uk, driving

Circular signs with red edges mean prohibition.  A white drawing on a blue background means something is mandatory.  What does a drawing on a sign with a blue edge mean?  Mandatory, recommended, informational?  For example, see [this Google Streetview image](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.422887,-1.0366486,3a,75y,14.61h,84.58t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1swNLN_ryXWoejgMhFXEc8BA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656):

[image]

Would caravans be required to follow the arrow to the right, or would they be allowed to go straight as well?  Or it purely a suggestion with no legal force?

Comment: I only remember this kind of signs (the blue border ones) from private ground, like the parking areas at road stops. Therefor I guess that they are not official.

Comment: It's actually the shape of the sign that gives you the meaning: round mandatory, square suggested, triangle danger.

Comment: @JoErNanO Except when I arrive a one-way street from the side; there will be a [rectangular white-on-blue arrow sign](https://www.verkeersborden.com/image/verkeersbordenproducts/c04.jpg), but it's mandatory, not suggested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These signs with the blue edges are found at service stations along motorways and are used for giving directions to certain services. This means that they are informational, however, these services only apply for the vehicle type specified.

For example, in the picture that sign is pointing towards parking but only for caravans. Therefore if the caravan doesn't require the parking then it can carry straight on to other services (refuelling). But if a car without a caravan were to use the parking space it would not be illegal, just impolite.

I hope this answered your question.

Comment: Whilst not illegal in a road trafic sense, there may be a fine levied by the land owner for disregarding their rules

Comment: I would suppose so, however this is probably not enforced very well.